# StringLengthAttribute doesn't seem to be working

Tags: data-annotations, validation, ria

Here is my Test class with data annotations:

```
class Test
{
  [Required, StringLength(10)]
  public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my console test program:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var test = new Test {
      MyProperty = "this is way more than 10 characters and should fail."
    };

    var context = new ValidationContext(test, null, null);

    // No exception here! (why not?)
    Validator.ValidateObject(test, context);

    test.MyProperty = null;

    // Exception here, as expected
    Validator.ValidateObject(test, context);
  }
}
```

For some reason, I do not get a validation exception when the string length is too long. I do get a validation exception (as expected) when I set the property to null and re-validate. Any ideas why my string length annotation is not being enforced?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a bit non-intuitive, but changing

```
Validator.ValidateObject(test, context);
```

to

```
Validator.ValidateObject(test, context, true);
```

solves the problem. The third argument is `bool validateAllProperties`. I'm not sure why the `[Required]` attribute was previously being enforced while the `[StringLength]` wasn't, but at least it all works now.

Comment: Thanks, this bit me today.

Comment: For me, it was `TryValidateObject` — and there's an overload that takes a fourth bool parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting this. I posted a bug on Microsoft Connect for this issue. I assume that they are incorrectly skipping a System.String property as it is not a value type because they do not do a deep/recursive validation without the "validateAllProperties" parameter.

Here's the bug link if you're interested:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672247/system-componentmodel-dataannotations-validator-does-not-validate-stringlengthattribute-unless-validateallproperties-specified

Comment: Connect is gone now, I'm curious, what came of this issue? Cause it's still seems to be bugged.

Comment: @mxmissile, not sure what happened to the bug because Microsoft Connect has been decommissioned. However, I think the code is in GitHub – maybe in dotnet/runtime – so it might be easier to determine what's going on and log an issue, if appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

It did not work for me in the WebAPI context. However, with little further research I found a solution.

Use ModelState.IsValid along with your data annotations to resolve this problem as follows:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

This will create a 400 (bad request) response to the caller as follows:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"reqs.ImportRows[0].SMSConsent":["The field SMSConsent must be a string with a maximum length of 1."]}}
```

The best part is, it provides the caller with the exact row number of the list if the request is a list object. This is very helpful to your 3rd party clients using your api to debug, analyze and fix the issue.